# Standard gravitational parameter - different formulas

Tags: gravity, astronomy, astrophysics, celestial-mechanics

Why we have two formulas for [Standard Gravitational Parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter):
$$\mu=GM \ 
\,{\rm and}\,
\mu = rv^2 \ .$$

I don't see any direct connection between the two formulas. How can we derive the second from the first? Is it somehow connected with this formula,
$$v_e = \sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first definition of $\mu=GM$ is the standard definition of the SGP. The second one comes from the velocity of a circular orbit. If you have an object in a circular orbit of radius $r$ and velocity $v$ around a body of mass $M$, then the velocity is given by
$$v=\sqrt{\frac{GM}{r}}$$

From this you can see that $rv^2=GM$ for circularly orbiting objects. Thus the two definitions are equivalent